Another way to make s3 folder objects public?
There's a way in the portal to click on the checkbox next to a folder within an s3 bucket, go to "Actions" drop down, and select "Make public using ACL". From my understanding this makes all objects in that folder public read accessible.
Is there a way to do this in an alternative way (from the cli perhaps)? I have a directory with ~1.7 million objects so if I try executing this action from the portal then it eventually just stops/times out around the 400k mark. I see that it's making a couple requests per object from my browser so maybe my local network is having issues I'm not sure.
I'd like to avoid applying a policy to the bucket. I have other buckets with less items and using the portal I have not run into this timeout issue before

ACLs are the old method for controlling access. Bucket policies are current best practice. I haven't done much with S3 for a while, but if you search for "S3 bucket policy public objects" or similar it'll probably become obvious fairly quickly https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/

Great thanks! I will look into using policies instead then if that's the better practice these days
